# Verify Element Is Within Viewport With Cypress

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress, end-to-end

Cypress's `visible` matcher treats an element as visible based on a variety of factors, however it doesn't take the viewport into account, so an element that is scrolled off-screen is still treated as visible.

I need to test that a link to an on-page anchor is functioning correctly. Once the link is clicked, the page scrolls to the element with the id as defined in the href of the link (`example/#some-id`).

**How can verify that the element is within the viewport?**

Comment: Have you looked at the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)?

Comment: @DavidThomas Cheers. I'd forgotten all bout that API

Comment: See also the discussion in [cypress-io/cypress#877](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/877).

Answer (score 15):

I've cobbled together the following commands which appear to work so far, but amazed there isn't on out-of-box solution:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('topIsWithinViewport', { prevSubject: true }, subject => {
  const windowInnerWidth = Cypress.config(`viewportWidth`);

  const bounding = subject[0].getBoundingClientRect();

  const rightBoundOfWindow = windowInnerWidth;

  expect(bounding.top).to.be.at.least(0);
  expect(bounding.left).to.be.at.least(0);
  expect(bounding.right).to.be.lessThan(rightBoundOfWindow);

  return subject;
})

Cypress.Commands.add('isWithinViewport', { prevSubject: true }, subject => {
  const windowInnerWidth = Cypress.config(`viewportWidth`);
  const windowInnerHeight = Cypress.config(`viewportHeight`);

  const bounding = subject[0].getBoundingClientRect();

  const rightBoundOfWindow = windowInnerWidth;
  const bottomBoundOfWindow = windowInnerHeight;

  expect(bounding.top).to.be.at.least(0);
  expect(bounding.left).to.be.at.least(0);
  expect(bounding.right).to.be.lessThan(rightBoundOfWindow);
  expect(bounding.bottom).to.be.lessThan(bottomBoundOfWindow);

  return subject;
})
```

Comment: @el-davo https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html

Answer (score 2):

I did a little refactoring on Undistracted's approach if anyone is interested:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('isWithinViewport', { prevSubject: true }, (subject) => {
  const rect = subject[0].getBoundingClientRect();

  expect(rect.top).to.be.within(0, window.innerHeight);
  expect(rect.right).to.be.within(0, window.innerWidth);
  expect(rect.bottom).to.be.within(0, window.innerHeight);
  expect(rect.left).to.be.within(0, window.innerWidth);

  return subject;
});

Cypress.Commands.add('isOutsideViewport', { prevSubject: true }, (subject) => {
  const rect = subject[0].getBoundingClientRect();

  expect(rect.top).not.to.be.within(0, window.innerHeight);
  expect(rect.right).not.to.be.within(0, window.innerWidth);
  expect(rect.bottom).not.to.be.within(0, window.innerHeight);
  expect(rect.left).not.to.be.within(0, window.innerWidth);

  return subject;
});
```

Uses `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` in case you have used `cy.viewport` before calling. Also uses `.within` to facilitate the outside addition.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me

```
cy.get(element).eq(index).then(($el) => {
        const bottom = Cypress.$(cy.state('window')).height()
        console.log("element", $el[0])
        const rect = $el[0].getBoundingClientRect()
        const isInViewport = (
            rect.top >= -2 &&
            rect.left >= 0 &&
            rect.bottom <= bottom &&
            rect.right <= Cypress.$(cy.state('window')).width()
        )
        expect(isInViewport).to.be.true
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant way so far

```
function isElementFullyVisible($el) {
    const rect = $el[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
        rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
        rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );
}

// Usage
const $element = $('#yourElementId'); // Replace with your selector
console.log(isElementFullyVisible($element));
```